# Python TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for class

Tags: python, class

Please help me understand this. I created a really simple program to try to understand classes.

```
class One(object):
    def __init__(self, class2):
        self.name = 'Amy'
        self.age = 21
        self.class2 = class2

    def greeting(self):
        self.name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
        print 'hi %s' % self.name

    def birthday(self):
        self.age = int(raw_input("What is your age?: "))
        print self.age 

    def buy(self):
        print 'You buy ', self.class2.name

class Two(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.name = 'Polly'
        self.gender = 'female'

    def name(self):
        self.gender = raw_input("Is she male or female? ")
        if self.gender == 'male'.lower():
            self.gender = 'male'
        else:
            self.gender = 'female'

        self.name = raw_input("What do you want to name her? ")

        print "Her gender is %s and her name is %s" % (self.gender, self.name)

Polly = Two()
Amy = One(Polly) 
# I want it to print 


Amy.greeting()
Amy.buy() 
Amy.birthday()
```

THE PROBLEM CODE

```
Polly.name() # TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Two.name(Polly)# Works. Why?
```

Why does calling the method on the class instance Polly not work? I'm pretty lost. I've looked  at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-May/022128.html and other Stackoverflow questions similiar to this, but I'm not getting it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `Two` has an instance method `name()`.  So `Two.name` refers to this method and the following code works fine:

```
Polly = Two()
Two.name(Polly)
```

However in `__init__()`, you override `name` by setting it to a string, so any time you create a new instance of `Two`, the `name` attribute will refer to the string instead of the function.  This is why the following fails:

```
Polly = Two()      # Polly.name is now the string 'Polly'
Polly.name()       # this is equivalent to 'Polly'()
```

Just make sure you are using separate variable names for your methods and your instance variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear explanation. I have a related question. What if I don't wish to set an initial name and just have the name set via raw_input? I get errors if I set `self.name = name
        self.gender = gender` and `init__(self, name, gender)` and then call it via `Polly = Two(name, gender)`, so I'm unclear about what to do here.

Comment: Think I may have gotten it. I'd just put those instance variables into the methods rather than __init__, or just set them to empty strings.

Comment: Don't do the `raw_input` work inside the class; separate responsibilities. People aren't responsible for figuring out what their names are; their names are assigned at birth, er, creation.

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting your `name` attribute with method called `name`. Just rename something.

Answer (score 1):

You have both a variable *and* a function called "name" in Two. Name one of them differently and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you get into the habit of carefully naming things. As you can see, even with very small pieces of code, you can get into trouble. You'll definitely want to read the Python style PEP very carefully. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/